# getting InvalidSelectorException while locating for an element using the using same xpath that works fine in firepath with 1 matching node

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, invalidselectorexception

[image]

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[Contains(Text(),'Forgot Password?')] because of the following error: 
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//a[Contains(Text(),'Forgot Password?')]' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

[image]

Comment: HTML is case-insensitive, but XPath is not, so while `//A[contains(text(),'Forgot Password?')]` can select anchor, `//a[Contains(Text(),'Forgot Password?')]` canNOT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error says it all, your xPath expression is not valid. You cannot change pre-defined keyword, like text() to Text(). Try `//a[contains(text(),'Forgot Password')]` or `//a[contains(.,'Forgot Password')]`

For more about InvalidSelectorException please refer [this](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/InvalidSelectorException.html).

Comment: thanks , i wasn't aware about the case sensitiveness of xpath

Comment: @KULDEEPSINGH Glad to Help!

Answer (score 3):

you have messed up with the syntax or expression you have entered

```
//a[Contains(Text(),'Forgot Password?')]
```

this has to be like

```
//a[contains(text(),'Forgot Password?')]
```